# How To Seperate the record values in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sql table like below

classids

```
2,3,4,5,
2,4,5,6,
5,9,6,8,
```

I want to split the comma separated values in sql

I want to give the condition

```
select classids from table name where classids = 2
```

Comment: The problem is that there *is* a table like that to begin with..

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions like below

```
SELECT CLASSIDS FROM TABLE WHERE CLASSIDS REGEXP '\b2\b'
```